# Strange view while in Thunderbird inbox

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, ubuntu-mate

[image]This is a view of when I am in my Thunderbird inbox?

What's going on?

Comment: Please, edit your question and add more information. If you ask laconic questions you rick to be downvoted and ignored. Don't asume that people can guess what happened to your system. Do explain!

Comment: @Cristiana Nicolae I added all the info that I had that I felt was relevant. I try my best, but can not always anticipate everything.